# Taking Odoo backup from a Linode Machine

Tags: ubuntu, odoo, odoo-8, linode

I have an ERP (Odoo) Installed on a Linode Machine. i want to take backup of DB and ERP files and save it on my local disk.

Comment: Great! And what's the question? What is your problem? What did you try?

Comment: @dome i have managed to create a zip and take ERP files backup from SSH console. For taking backup of database i trying to figure out how can i get it from SSH, i mean what would be the syntax to list all the databases, what would be console comman to create a backup file.